# Measurability of "conditional" pushforward measure

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P$ be a standard probability space, and $T$, $R$ compact spaces. $F:\Omega\times T \to R$ a measurable function, which can be seen as a random function $T\to R$. Let $\mu$ be a deterministic Radon probability measure on $T$.

Is the application  $\Omega \to Prob(R) : \omega \mapsto F(\omega,\cdot) * \mu$ a measurable map ? In other terms, can we define $F*\mu$ as a random measure ?

For which $\sigma$-field on $Prob(R)$ ? The one generated by all the maps $\nu \mapsto \nu(B)$ or the Borel $\sigma$-field associated to weak convergence ? Are those actually the same ?

Comment: Honestly I think I might not understand the question, but this seems related to the problem/question of existence of regular conditional distributions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_conditional_probability Many of the keywords seem related: pushforward, conditional, random probability measure. Let me know if I am grossly misunderstanding the question. Anyway the short answer is that unless the probability space is really bad (not a Borel space, not measurably equivalent to some subset of an infinite unit cube) then it should be possible to make it work.